# How do I ensure that JavaFX is using the platform-specific DirectoryChooser implementation

Tags: linux, user-interface, javafx, directory

When I open a JavaFX DirectoryChooser (or FileChooser) on my Linux system and set the initial directory, the path I provide gets converted to canonical form.

The result is users getting exposed to details of the disk environment. The user expects to find their data in a directory like /home/user1/Documents/MyAppData but /home is on a small system disk and "user1" is a symlink to a location on a large data disk, so they actually see the underlying "real" path /MassiveDataDisk/users/user1/Documents/MyAppData in the DirectoryChooser dialog.

Worse still, if the user synchs their work to another machine (which is how I spotted this problem) then any paths set by calls to the DirctoryChooser do no necessarily work if the underlying config of the second machine is different, such as  "MassiveDataDisk" having been created as "MassiveDatadisk". Clearly machine configs can be corrected, but as the developer, I shouldn't need to know about symlinks in the directory structure like that, and don't want to expose the user to it.

So far as I can see, this happens in the CommonDialogs code under com.sun.glass.ui where a method called convertFolder uses the canonical form method on File before passing the result to the native DirectoryChooser. By deliberately causing an error I got a stack trace confirming that the CommonDialogs code is being used.

I can also see that there is a CommonDialogsGtk class which I assume should be the one used in a Linux environment, and that does not force that conversion to canonical form. I can't see how to make Java use that platform-specific code.

Does anyone know if there is some configuration detail that I'm missing? I expected the JavaFX environment to autodetect the right DirectoryChooser to use.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")`may suggest a suitable initial value.

Comment: I don't think that's going to help because the CommonDialogs code takes a java File  and explicitly calls getCanonicalFile(), which gets the real path and loses any symlinks. System.getProperty("user.home") gives something like "/home/user1", but in the environments I'm working on, "user1" is a symlink and the getCanonicalFile() call translates it all into the real path.

Comment: Maybe [`Files.readSymbolicLink()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path))?

Comment: @trashgod I don't think the symbolic link is the problem in and of itself. The problem is that _internal code_ used by `DirectoryChooser` calls `File#getCanonicalFile()` and that resolves the "real" file path, and the OP does not want that to happen. Given this is done by internal code, it doesn't matter _how_ the user gets the `File` argument they pass as the initial directory of the `DirectoryChooser`.

Comment: When you wrote ```CommonDialogsGtk``` were you actually referring to ```GtkCommonDialogs``` (https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/gtk/GtkCommonDialogs.java)? Given what you have written, my suggestion is that you file a bug report at https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/. You might also post your question on the forum: https://community.oracle.com/community/java/javafx/javafx_2.0_and_later

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I was referring to GtkCommonDialogs, Thanks for the suggestions - I will follow up.